# Jquery.ajax PUT data not parsed by PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, slim

I am using the Slim PHP Framework and am trying to send FormData using Jquery.ajax() in the following way:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('some_name', 'some_data');
data.append('a_file', $('input[name=the_file_form_field]').get(0).files[0]));

$.ajax({
    url: 'the_destination_url',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //Processing result here
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //Processing result here
    }
});
```

However, I tried the following scenarios:

- **Works**: Formdata without a file, adding _METHOD=PUT and setting $.ajax to type: POST
- **Doesn't work (php receives no PUT data)**: Formdata without a file, setting $.ajax to type: PUT
- **Doesn't work (method stays POST)**: Formdata with a file, adding _METHOD=put and setting $.ajax to type: POST
- **Doesn't work (php receives no PUT data)**: Formdata with a file, setting $.ajax to type: PUT

Is there anything I'm missing?

the application requires it to use a PUT request and as such a POST request is no possibility.

Comment: Please specify `doesn't work`. Is the server not responding correctly? or is the ajax not receiving a correct response?

Comment: The server is not receiving (or parsing) the PUT data correctly, the request body in the chrome console clearly shows it's generated correctly though

Comment: And how exactly are we now able to help you with your problem, if the server receives a valid PUT-request but is probably not working correctly? I think everybody of us wants to be a visionary, but we aren't.

Comment: Well for example by telling me if the jQuery is correct, or perhaps if anyone has had the same experience in the Slim framework. Anything non-condescending really.

Comment: What web server are you using and how are you serving PHP (`php-fpm`, `mod_php`)?

Comment: running a basic Linux web server running apache2 with mod_php

Comment: It's possible that this is mod_php's fault. Can you swap to `php-fpm` and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the comments from people posting in: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=26004

Apparently PHP silently discards all incoming POST data whenever the `post_max_size` directive is exceeded.

Aside from `post_max_size` it's also smart to check the `upload_max_filesize` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to send data as an object. 
e.g.

```
data: {'formData' : data},
```

**Your Ajax request should look like**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'the_destination_url',
    data: {'formData' : data},
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //Processing result here
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //Processing result here
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the request body will result in [Object object], this would work when the request type was GET or POST

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to get PUT data sent from Ajax JQuery in PHP is:

Send your data Like this in JavaScript:

> where mydata is {k1 : "val1" , "k2" : "val2" , }

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "data.php",
     contentType : "json",
     data : mydata,
     method:"PUT",
     success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
     },
     error: function (err) {
         console.log(err);
     },
     complete:function (e) {
         console.log(e);
     }
 });
```

The way to get the data in data.php file is:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$putVars);
var_dump( $putVars ); // input from your form
```